# Range of values for convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** For $a>0$. the series $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a^{\log_e n}$$

is convergent for which range of values of $a$?

**My Approach:**

The divergence test of checking $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n =0 $ gives $0<a<1$

So does the ratio test and the root test.

I am fairly new to this topic, so I am not sure how to proceed.

**Edit:** The answer is $0<a<1/e$ I fail to see how they arrive at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

This is indeed a *Riemann series*, since you can rewrite its general term as
$$a^{\log n}=\mathrm e^{\log n\log a}=n^{\log a}.$$
As $\sum_n n^\alpha$ converges if and only if $\alpha <-1$, this yields
$$\log a<-1\iff 0<a<\dfrac1{\mathrm{e}}.$$

Comment: I looked up Riemann series, but could not make the jump. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I have edited question details.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: (+1) Yes, it is. Thanks.